# Python declaring multiple variable confusion

Tags: python, variables, fibonacci

I would like to know why this code is giving me two different solution:

```
a = 0
b = 1
solution = 0

while b <= 4000000:
    if b % 2 == 0:
        solution += b
    a, b = b, a + b

print(solution)
```

in this case the `solution` is 4613732. However when I try this code:

```
a = 0
b = 1
solution = 0

while b <= 4000000:
    if b % 2 == 0:
        solution += b
    a = b
    b = a + b

print(solution)
```

the `solution` is 4194302

Any suggestions?

Comment: `a, b = b, a + b` VS `a = b` and `b = a + b`

Comment: Keep in mind that the RHS always gets evaluated first, and you'll find this is not very surprising.

Comment: use print statements to debug and understand the code

Comment: the first one is simultaneous assignment, the second is procedural one  where  b gets the updated value.

Comment: @yosemite_k: mind that the assignment is not simultaneously in the sense that these are assigned concurrently or even without one being able to influence one another. The assignment is done left-to-right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The difference explained

Because you write:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

In your second approach. That means that **after the first line, `a` has the value of `b`**. And the second line will produce `b = a + b = b + b` so two times `b`. In other words, the second one will actually walk through the powers of two.

That is not happening in the first approach, since you write:

```
a, b = b, a + b
```

As a result you **first construct a tuple `(b,a+b)`** (with `a` and `b` the *old* values). **Next you *unpack*** that tuple into `a` and `b` again. But you first evaluated `a + b` with the old values. That is the essential difference.

## More efficient approach

You want to sum up the *even* Fibonacci numbers. You can however to this more efficiently. If you do an analysis on the Fibonacci sequence, you will find out that it is structured:

```
o o e o o e o o e ...
```

with `o` being an *odd* number, and `e` being an *even* number. So you can simply work with **hops of three**, like:

```
a = 1
b = 2
solution = 0

while b <= 4000000:
    solution += b
    a,b = a+2*b,2*a+3*b

print(solution)
```

Here we thus save on *iterations* and on checks whether `b` is *even*: we simply know that it is always even.

When using `timeit` (with Python 3.5.3 and GCC 6.3.0 on linux), we obtain the following results:

```
original   3.4839362499988056
optimized  1.5940769709995948  45.755%
```

So the average runtime of the optimized program is about half of the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because, all expressions at the right side of the assignment operator gets evaluated first.

So let's say you have the code below:

```
a = 5
b = 7
a, b = b, a + b
```

You expect `a` to be assigned with the value 7 and then `b` to be assigned with the value 14, the sum of `a` and `b` using the new value of `a`.

In fact, on the right side of the `=` operator, `b` is evaluated to 7 and `a+b` is evaluated to 12

```
a, b = 7, 12
```